# Applying Filter to Multi Dimensional Numpy Array ,eg: Cifar10 Data

Tags: python, numpy

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
# load dataset
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = cifar10.load_data()
# summarize loaded dataset
print('Train: X=%s, y=%s' % (trainX.shape, trainy.shape))
print('Test: X=%s, y=%s' % (testX.shape, testy.shape))
```

> Train: X=(50000, 32, 32, 3), y=(50000, 1)

> Test: X=(10000, 32, 32, 3), y=(10000, 1)

```
trainMask = (trainy == 1) | (trainy == 8) | (trainy == 9)
testMask  = (testy == 1)  | (testy == 8)  | (testy == 9)
```

## HOW TO FILTER THE TRAIN AND TEST BASED ON MASK ? like..

trainX = trainX[trainMask] ,

testX  = testX[testMask]

trainy = trainy[trainMask] .. One Dimention Works..
Not trainX = trainX[trainMask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is `np.where()`. see the code

```
TrainX = TrainX[np.where(trainMask)]
TestX = TestX[np.where(testMask)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
trainX = trainX[trainMask.flatten()]
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. It selects the images not from the index of labels but it uses the labels themselves as index. so from 50k images only the first 10 will be selected 50 thousand times.

Comment: It is correct, `trainMask` is an array containing boolean values and has shape (50_000, 1). It holds `True` at indices where `(trainy == 1) | (trainy == 8) | (trainy == 9)` and `False` otherwise. It's called boolean indexing, look up numpy documentation: [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: you are right. I misread your code I thought it's `trainX[trainy.flatten()]`